# When I enter a letter, my function works but when I enter an integer it doesnt

Tags: arrays, c, function

I am trying to create a function that will ask the user to input a number to determine the size of an array and then input numbers into the array. I then need to print the array and interchange the smallest and largest numbers in it. This is in C language

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_array();
void display_array();

void read_array(int arr[])
{
    int Size;
    printf("Enter the desired size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &Size);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a number for position %d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        getchar();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    int arr[size];
    
    read_array(arr[size]);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you use a tag with C,it is already clear you are using c  and no need to write this code in c-language and attach part of the display_array() too.

Comment: `int size; int arr[size];` is invalid -- you are defining a variable-length array using a length that is undefined.  Either choose a _maximum_ array size that your program can handle, or dynamically allocate an array, or read the size _before_ defining the array.

Comment: Array sizes are fixed in the moment of creation, and you create this with uninitialized variable size. Also there should be a compilation error for the code `read_array(arr[size]);`, check your compiler messages.

Comment: You *must* *always* check the value returned by `scanf`.  In this case, you could do `for(int i = 0; i < Size && scanf("%d", arr + i) == 1; i += 1) { ... }`. (Assuming you fix the initialization of `arr` as described in other comments).  There's no need for the `getchar`; the `%d` conversion specifier will consume leading whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the creation of the array, you have 3 options (ordered by my own preference).

In this example `get_array_size()` is a function that returns the number of elements entered by the user and `process_array()` does something with the created array (like filling it with more user input).

1.) Use a fixed length array

```
int array[10];
unsigned int size = get_array_size();

if (size > 10) {
    printf("Size is too large.\n");
    exit(1);
}

process_array(array, size);
```

This has the benefit that it's always clear how much memory your program will consume: 10 elements of the size of `int`.

Obviously, if the user enters a number less than `10` (in this example) the remainder of the array would be "wasted".

2.) Allocate the array on the heap

```
unsigned int size = get_array_size();

// It's still advised to "cap" the max. size of your array
if (size > 32) {
    printf("Won't allocate: size is too large.\n");
    exit(1);
}

int *array;

array = calloc(size, sizeof(int));

if (!array) {
    printf("Could not allocate memory!\n")
    exit(1);
}

process_array(array, size);
free(array);
```

Note the use of the [`free()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) function.

Here only what is needed/requested will be allocated (if the user enters `5` only `5` elements will be allocated).

Downside is you have to `free()` the allocated memory once you're done with it.

And even here, it's very much advised to set a maximum number of elements anyway (you don't want your program to, say, allocate 4GB of ram for a simple task that doesn't *require* it)

3.) Allocate the array on the stack

```
unsigned int size = get_array_size();

// It's still advised to "cap" the max. size of your array
if (size > 32) {
    printf("Won't allocate: size is too large.\n");
    exit(1);
}

int array[size];

process_array(array, size);
```

Same as option 2 except that you don't `free()` the memory after use. However, other limitations come into play (you can't return an array allocated like this from a function) and you definitely don't want to overflow your stack.

So you see, no matter which option you choose: it's practically always needed to enforce a maximum anyway, so I'd go with the first option whenever possible (consider stack size).

In all cases, the `process_array` function can be implemented in the same way (the function doesn't care *where* the memory is coming from):

```
void process_array(int *array, unsigned int size) {
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
          // do something with array[i]
     }
}
```

The bottom line is: if you want to program in C, you **really** have to understand these concepts. If this is too much for you, choose another language that does the memory handling for you.